# How to implement a generic data type to another struct's method?

Tags: rust, traits

I have this code:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Counter {
    pub calories: f64,
}

pub struct Protein {
    pub weight_in_kg: f64,
}

pub struct Fat {
    pub weight_in_kg: f64,
}

impl Counter {
    fn eat(&mut self, food: T) {
        self.calories += food.gives();
    }
}

pub trait Food {
    fn gives(&self) -> f64;
}

impl Food for Protein {
    fn gives(&self) -> f64 {
        self.weight_in_kg * 4.0
    }
}

impl Food for Fat {
    fn gives(&self) -> f64 {
        self.weight_in_kg * 9.0
    }
}
```

Which gives this error:

> fn eat(&mut self, food: T) {
> ^ not found in this scope

`T` can either be `Protein` or `Fat`. But I am not sure where to implement `T` to get it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make `eat` a generic, like this:

```rs
impl Counter {
    // This means make a copy of this method for every used value of `T`
    // Use :Food to make sure `T` can only be food
    fn eat<T: Food>(&mut self, food: T) {
        self.calories += food.gives();
    }
}
```

Alternatively:

```rs
impl Counter {
    // This method is often used if you need more complex trait bounds.
    fn eat<T>(&mut self, food: T)
        where T: Food
    {
        self.calories += food.gives();
    }
}
```

You can also make the entire `struct` a generic, in that case each counter can eat only one kind of food.

Comment: it did the job! thanks a lot.

Comment: @volkan others put effort on solve your doubt. Please, accept their response and upvote it if worked for you

Comment: @AlexVergara It's ok, OP is free to accept or not to. If he chooses not to after a gentle reminder that's his own choice.

Comment: @AlexVergara I’m pretty new to stack overflow, so I missed this. thanks and will do!